# How can I make new entries that require image in strapi from flutter web?

Tags: flutter, strapi

I want to make a new entry for my collection type from my flutter web that need image for its cover field, the image is from media library in strapi.

This is how I try to send the post request using multipart request that I got from following tutorial about multipart request from YouTube:

```
addArtikel(String judul, String isiRich, String cover) async {
    final token = await SecureStorrage.getToken();
    var request =
        await http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse("$baseURL/artikel"));
    request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
    request.fields['judul'] = judul;
    request.fields['isiRich'] = isiRich;

    var image = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'cover',
        (await rootBundle.load('http://localhost:1337$cover'))
            .buffer
            .asUint8List());
    request.files.add(image);
    var response = await request.send();
    var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
    var result = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);

    print(result);
  }
```

and here is the error that I got:

[image: error message]

From the error that I got, I guess this way only works if the image is in flutter asset and not from my localhost/internet.

Is there a way I can make new entries using image from strapi media library?